# Cambiar ruta de angular sin hacer reload de views ni controller

Tags: angularjs, nodejs

Estoy creando una plataforma web con angularjs y nodejs, tengo un inconveniente con la función de cambiar el idioma.

**Routing:**

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/:lang?/index', {
    templateUrl: 'modules/Home/HomeView.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  });
```

**Ejemplo url:**
http://localhost:1337/en/index

View parte de cambio de idiomas:

```html
<ng-repeat ng-repeat="lang in availableLangs track by $index">
      <li><a href="" ng-class="{'active': lang === currentLanguage}" ng-click="translate(lang)"> {{lang}}</a></li>
      <li ng-if=" $index < availableLangs.length - 1">|</li>
    </ng-repeat>
```

Controller, función translate

```js
$scope.translate = function (langKey) {
      if ($routeParams.lang) {
        $route.updateParams({ lang: langKey });
      }
      $translate.use(langKey);
      $scope.showLangSelector = false;
    };
```

Este me está funcionando, pero me recargar otra vez el controller y la vista, quiero saber si hay una opción de solo hacer el cambio de la url en el parámetro :lang pero sin tener que hacer reload.

Gracias